# How to show foreign key side-by-side with another table?

Tags: sql

I have a table called users, which has columns username, password, and userlevel. Userlevel is a foreign key that points to another table called userlevels, which has two columns: level and permission.

How do I show the permission side-by side with the user table?

I've tried doing:

```
select username, u.userlevel, l.permission from users u, userlevels l 
where l.permission in 
(select permission from userlevels x where x.userlevel = l.level)
```

But this appears to be giving me a bunch of duplicates. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some example data and the expected result?

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Comment: @AllanChua high-security bank software. don't worry it's not sql-injectable

Comment: Oh I see, What i mean is are you trying to put it in C# code or whatever language do you use because SQL queries variates.

Comment: Also, kudos for doing normalization correctly and not duplicating info in your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use what's called an [inner join.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
CREATE VIEW MyView as select * from users inner join userlevels where users.userlevel = userslevel.permissions;
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! Will accept once timer is up.

Comment: Edited my post to show you how to create a view with the stuff you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select username, u.userlevel, l.permission 
    from users u  
    join userlevels l on u.userlevel = l.level
```